# mysql threads running high issue for Percona Mysql 8.0.16

Tags: mysql

we are experiencing a threads running high issue

```
mysql> show global status like '%buffer_pool%'
    -> ;
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                           | Value                                            |
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status          | Dumping of buffer pool not started               |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status          | Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191011  8:32:57 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status        |                                                  |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data           | 7342440                                          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data           | 120298536960                                     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty          | 1098108                                          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty          | 17991401472                                      |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed        | 32982303                                         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free           | 13213728                                         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_LRU_flushed    | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_not_young | 58099577                                         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_made_young     | 64937403                                         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc           | 415352                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_old            | 2710229                                          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total          | 20971520                                         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd       | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead           | 55106                                            |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests        | 344963685851                                     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads                | 6418361                                          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free            | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests       | 17527245765                                      |
+-----------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Could anyone please advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lots of threads?  Do `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.  If most say `Sleep`, then there is nothing to worry about.

Load Average = 2 and CPU = 15%.  Do you have 16 cores in your CPU?  Of so, that says you are using about 2 of the 16.  Again, no problem.

Are queries taking a long time?  Let's see them, their `EXPLAIN`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

How much RAM do you have?  How big is your dataset?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?